# What to do in the Flowerful Tower mystery room in Disgaea 5?

Tags: disgaea-5

Playing Disgaea 5, I found a mystery room in the item world which looks like Flowerful. There is a pirate at the entrance saying "What's at the top of that tower?". I have explored the map, and certainly there are several pillars, but I cannot seem to find any way to get any higher up.

I couldn't find anything in this map. What am I supposed to do here, and what is there to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the triple jump ability, which is granted by the Life Support Unit at level 4, (and probably a high level on the character you use to walk around) to get to the top of the tower. If you manage to reach the top, you can talk with the item god, who offers you to duplicate the item you are in. If he succeeds (failure chance seems to be around 50%) you get an identical copy of the item (level, stats and innocents).